# How to automatically add final modifier to local variables and parameters on reformatting code using intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting PMD warnings in my intellij project and want to automatically add final modifier to local variables and parameters by just refactoring the code.

Comment: Does not seem to be implemented at the momen: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137056

Comment: A plugin is available: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7449-insert-final-modifier
(I have no affiliation with it and never used it.)

Comment: Something to transform a variable effectively final into a final variable. It exist in eclipse, might be a good start to search a similar feature for Intellij. But note that since java 8 "effective final", it is not really necessary, adding `final` everywhere will be noisy...

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing the [Save actions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions) plugin. I've highlighted the options that will do the trick for you in below screenshot:
[image: screenshot of save actions plugin]

Downside, it only works while actually modifying the file, so it will not allow you to refactor your whole project and immediately fix all PMD warnings. See it more as a solution for the longer term :-)